# Userstyle Overwrite HTML Attribute

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a CSS style sheet for userstyles.org. I have ran into an issue where there are some HTML attributes that need to be overwritten but I have not been able to figure out how to with CSS.

I have tried to do div[style="text-shadow"] and others.

Here is the code in question

```
<div class="child_container">

   <div style="color: #4F565A; font-size: 12px; text-shadow: 1px 1px #FFFFFF; word-wrap: break-word;">

      <span style="color: #347DB5;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;padding-bottom: 15px;">
         Live Preview
      </span>
      <div class="body markdown sgpPreview">
        <p>a</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to overwrite the text-shadow attribute in this case.

Comment: Where did you leave all the `<` signs?

Comment: @MrLister It wouldnt let me post it in the code if I didnt take it off

Comment: @MrLister hmm idk. When I tried it. It said something about needing to take the span out etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the attributes you want to overide, e.g.

```
div[style] {
   text-shadow: none !important;
   }
```

Comment: I make myself feel stupid every time I dont think of the simple things. Thanks, it worked and I will mark it answered in the next 7 minutes